# The property 'Exit' was not found in type 'Application'

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

[image]

My **App.xaml** code doesn't recognize the [`Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.exit?view=netcore-3.1) property and I have no idea why. The **App.xaml.cs** code doesn't recognize `ExitEVentArgs` either.

Comment: Don't use WPF documentation.  Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication?view=winrt-19041), no argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The property 'Exit' was not found in type 'Application'

Hans Passant is correct, UWP platform [`Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application?view=winrt-19041) does not contain `Exit` **event**, but it has `Exit` method, you could call it to exit current app manually.

if you want to detect app is existing, you could listen [`Suspending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending?view=winrt-19041) event that Occurs when the application transitions to Suspended state from some other state.

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Construct();
    this.Suspending += App_Suspending;
}

private void App_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    
}
```

For more detail, please refer [UWP life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).